# vb.net : DPFP.Error.SDKException: Verification Failure

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am having a problem with my fingerprint verification using vb.net 2010. I am not sure if what makes the error every time i verify the template from my mysql database. Below is the error message. I am using digital persona u.are.u 4000b as my fingerprint scanner.
[image]

and this is my code for verification:

```
 DrawPicture(ConvertSampleToBitmap(Sample))

    Dim features As DPFP.FeatureSet = ExtractFeatures(Sample, DPFP.Processing.DataPurpose.Verification)

    conn.Open()
    cmd.Connection = conn
    cmd.CommandText = "Select * from emp_t"
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

    If dr.HasRows Then
        While dr.Read()

            Dim MemStream As IO.MemoryStream
            Dim fpBytes As Byte()

            fpBytes = dr(2)
            MemStream = New IO.MemoryStream(fpBytes)

            Dim templa8 As DPFP.Template = New DPFP.Template()
            templa8.DeSerialize(MemStream)

            Me.Template = templa8

            ' Check quality of the sample and start verification if it's good
            If Not features Is Nothing Then
                ' Compare the feature set with our template
                Dim result As DPFP.Verification.Verification.Result = New DPFP.Verification.Verification.Result()
                Try
                    Verificator.Verify(features, templa8, result)
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox(ex.ToString)
                End Try
                If result.Verified Then
                    MessageBox.Show("Verified")
                    Exit Sub
                Else
                    MessageBox.Show("The fingerprint was NOT VERIFIED!")
                End If
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Fingerprint sample is not established!")
            End If


        End While
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("No record found!")
    End If

    conn.Close()
```

I been struggling for months in searching for the solution on my problem. To anyone who can share there thoughts and extends help will be much much appreciated... Thank you...